# gui design question

Tags: python, design-patterns, user-interface, tkinter

I use tkinter, but my question is probably general.

This is the first time I'm designing GUI. Each of my objects is modeled as a class. I don't understand how to tie the GUI class hierarchy with the rest of the class hierarchy.

For example, I have creatures:

```
# this is before I had any GUI in my code
class Creature:
  def current_position() # returns real-time x, y coords
    # ...
```

I want to display them as circles that move around on a canvas. It seemed reasonable to me that the graphical representation of movement should be provided by a method `update_display` in `class Creature`. However, that means that `class Creature` has to know the details about the GUI. In addition, the `class App(tkinter.Tk)` with a `redraw` method would need to know the list of all existing `Creature` instances in order to call their `update_display` methods. That's way too much dependency.

What's the right approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generally accepted pattern for this is called model/view/controller. You have a controller object that both knows about all the creatures (your "model") and about the GUI (your "view"). The controller is then responsible for connecting the two. For example, your view could have a "draw_creature" method which accepts a creature as input. The controller would then iterate over the creatures, passing then one-by-one to the view. Or, each creature has a "draw" method that accepts a view as a parameter, and the view asks each creature to draw itself, passing it a reference to the view.

With this pattern in place you could easily have multiple views but the creatures don't have to be updated to know about them. Likewise, you could change how you store and manage creatures and the view doesn't need to know anything about that.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any reference I should go to read more about it? (Or is it as straightforward as it seems?)

Comment: With one approach, it would seem that creatures would need to know about whether I'm using tk or some other GUI framework - otherwise how can they draw themselves even when passed a view as a reference? With the other approach, the GUI would need to know quite a lot about the creatures if it can draw them just based on the creature reference. It's still better than what I struggled with originally - but it doesn't completely remove the dependency between the GUI and the model. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @max - you are correct. The amount of decoupling is a factor of how much time you want to invest. Typically your model should be view-agnostic. The view, however, needs to be know about the objects it has to work with. You cant create a view and have it work for all possible models. The view needs a loose coupling with your creatures. For example, it can know to call 'get_position" or "get_name', etc. The abstraction simply means it doesnt have to know how tney are created, stored, etc.

Comment: @max: google for "model view controller" for more information. There are plenty of references on tne web. Wikipedia probably has as good a description as any.

Comment: @max: one other comment: just because the view needs to be passed an object yo render, it doesnt have to be _the_ object. The view merely exposes an interface to the controller. For example, it would expose a "draw" method that takes a Drawable object that has a method "get_position". Its up to you whether a Creature object is "drawable" or if the controller takes a model object and converts it to a "drawable"object. So, the view doesnt need to know about "creatures" per se, only drawable objects. Its up to you whether a creature is directly drawable or not.

Comment: To avoid reinventing wheels, I suggest that you take a look at the ["Design Patterns"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) book.

Comment: I found one example of MVC in Python: http://dpip.testingperspective.com/?p=18. Can I assume that it's reasonably representative and can provide direction in my situation? If anyone has more examples, please let me know!

Comment: And thanks Bryan for all the explanations.. They are very helpful, especially the one about view having to know the model, and objects passed to view not having to be the actual objects in the model.